# Why do I keep getting an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop

I keep getting an infinite loop? What do i have to change to fix this? I am a beginner. Please help. I cant figure this out. I tried playing around with all the other loops but keep getting the same error.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int inputData();
int convertData();
int outputData();

int main ()
{
inputData();
return 0;
}

int inputData ()
{
int hours, minutes;
char am_pm;

cout << "Please enter hours: "; // ask user to input hours.
cin >> hours; 
do
{
if (hours > 23)
{
cout << "ERROR! Must be less than 23" << endl;
}
} 
while (hours > 23); // end of hours loop

cout << "Please enter minutes: ";
cin >> minutes;
do
{
if (minutes > 59)
{
cout << "Must be less than 59. Try again!" << endl;
}
}
while (minutes > 59);
}
```

Comment: All the cool kids are doing indentation. You should try it.

Comment: I don't see that you change the variables you base the loops on within those loops. How would they ever terminate? Try moving the input inside the loop, after the `do {`.

Comment: You excluded the user input from your error checking loop. Since you do not get a new value for hours, once it's invalid it will forever be invalid.

Comment: There is nothing to stop the loops from running forever.

Comment: There's no way for someone to enter a new input within the loops, therefore the loop condition variables don't change.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation can save your life.

```
---> do {
|     if (hours > 23) {
|       cout << "ERROR! Must be less than 23" << endl;
|      }
---  } while (hours > 23); // end of hours loop
```

For example, your first cycle (even the second) checks always the same condition but does not modify the state of your program, so how do you expect it will change the termination condition?

It should be something like (**very minimal**):

```
do {
  std::cin >> hours;
  if (hours > 23) {
    std::cout << "Error\n";
  }
} while (hours > 23);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `hour prompting statements` ie. `cout << "Please enter hours: "; // ask user to input hours.
cin >> hours;` to the `do block` of the loop.

```
do {
  cout << "Please enter hours: "; // ask user to input hours.
  cin >> hours;

  if (hours > 23)
  {
    cout << "ERROR! Must be less than 23" << endl;
  }
} while (hours > 23); // end of hours loop
```

So that if the user enters an invalid hour, he will be re-prompted until he enters a valid hour.